# Editing somebody else's question to appeal to a broader audience

Tags: discussion, editing

This is my first time posting on any meta, so sorry if it's an inappropriate question in some way.

Before I had edit privileges, I gave a fairly popular answer to [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/training-community-for-image-video-processing/2622#2622). A question was, in my opinion, a little bit too specific for a "growing knowledge base", as I usually look at SO and now DSP.SE, but I tried providing a general answer.

My answer is the only one, but as I indicated in the comment I left below the question, I think it would be good to have other people's input on this. I have also suggested to the author of the question to edit the question in a way I believe would still ask for the specific information from the original post, but also be appealing to a broader reader pool and call for a less specific answer.

Now, I got edit privileges. I can see that the OP of the question is regularly on the site, he just chose to ignore my comment: he didn't edit, or comment on why he thinks it is not a good idea. I would still like to see that post edited in that direction (edit it myself). I've looked through *metas* to confirm if my edit in the suggested direction would be considered good practice, or not, but I could not find anything useful.

Could you please give some general advice on when it is acceptable to edit other people's questions, and also, *if you think it is a good idea to edit this specific post the way I would like to*?

**Edit** I did not get edit privileges yet, just taught I did, but the rest of the question still applies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that editing is appropriate in for this specific case. Editing is meant for improving clarity of a question, not to change its semantics. A good rundown of when to edit is given [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit).

Nevertheless, the title of the question does appear to be a little misleading, so editing that to reflect the meaning of the question better would be appropriate. This would also largely solve the problem of appeal to a larger audience, since most of us search by title.